# Using maven with main class

Tags: java, maven

I need a little bit startup help. I'm new with the maven stuff and it just don't work.
I copied some solutions from guides, but I did something wrong.

So first of all I understood I need a pom.xml to define all project settings. So I set `modelversion` `groupid` `artefactid` and `version` .

Further I need a special plugin to build for java >9 : `maven-compiler-plugin`  and  `<maven.compiler.release>14</maven.compiler.release>` .

So now I want to build a .jar file containing all dependencies and the main manifest.
So I'm using the shade plugin. After that `mvn package` should create a runable jar.

My pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.exp</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>14</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <transformers>
                                    <transformer
                                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                        <mainClass>de.exp.MainStarter</mainClass>
                                    </transformer>
                                </transformers>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

My main-class

```java
package de.exp;

public class MainStarter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

But the resulting .jar file isn't runnable. I get the message `no main manifest attribute, in target/my-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Answer (score 0):

I think your `plugin` is at the wrong place... If you take a look closer, you setup the `plugins` under `pluginsManagement` which is used for multi-project configuration, when you want to configure plugins for all your sub-modules. But each module, in order to use this, needs to define a section `build>plugins/plugin`.

In your case, here is the correct structure your POM is supposed to have :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            ...
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I exactly followed such a guide. That lead to the actual pom file. But I did something wrong and I wanted to ask you for help, so I can find the problem and can prevent it the next time.

Comment: What guide are you following ?

Comment: Thank you for the answere. I did compied that from somewhere. Now I corrected it and it works !